# User permissions based MEF components

Tags: c#, authentication, user-controls, mef

I did my first steps toward MEF few month ago and everything seemed to be okay till now. What I want to do is to use MEF in now of my real applications and load or we can say display UI components based on authenticated users permissions. I am developing patient management system for clinic and I want to implement scenario where MEF composed UI components are displayed based on user type. for example if authenticated user is doctor I want to show particular components and hid others.

What I am trying to achieve is something like

`ISystemComponent` which has some properties and methods so administration can control each user access level and based on DB records MEF composed controls will be displayed to the end-user. I also think of using MetaData interface while exporting components so using this how can I get the desired result?

any right direction will be appreciated

Comment: Target presentation layer? WPF or WinForms?

Comment: not winforms but WPF or it might be silverlight as well

Comment: You have several frameworks which does exactly what you want, e.g. PRISM (which may use MEF or other IOC container)

Comment: Can u suggest any other IoC than PRISM we do not want to implement PRISM.

Answer (score 4):

I did this by using an metadata attribute for a module ID and a table that has the permissions .

Do a ImportMany on the interface then filter it based on the metadata attribute using reflection and compare to the permissions in the table.

This blog post describes all the MEF involved.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2010/01/20/mef-for-beginner-metadata-part-8.aspx

**Other Links..**

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2010/01/09/mef-for-beginner-toc.aspx

http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata&referringTitle=Guide

[MEF Plugins with Security and Profiles Efficency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006332/mef-plugins-with-security-and-profiles-efficency)

[MEF with ImportMany and ExportMetadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909067/mef-with-importmany-and-exportmetadata)

**This will show how to import from xaml**

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2010/03/20/mef-for-beginner-import-from-xaml-part-11.aspx

Comment: thank u those links are really helpful for me I exactly thougt of using metadata and use some sort of collection inside attribute to manage access policy and the while composition check if currently authenticated user has same permission and only in this case show plugin to the user

Answer (score 2):

The article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/dynecoratorMefAop.aspx) details using AOP to inject security concerns into MEF. This could be one way of doing this - I havent' found anything in MEF that would allow this sort of functionality elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think PRISM can do exactly what you've described. Take a look at [this Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/PrismTutorial_Part1.aspx). You can create several module catalogs (according to user permissions), and load catalog dynamically from XML as described [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943055.aspx):

```
var catalog = ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(new Uri("catalog.xaml", 
                                                 UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: I do not use PRISM and it is not planed to be used in our project we bui8ld many things from the beginning as this is really enterprise system

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this in WPF / MVVM using [Cinch](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CinchV2_1.aspx) and backend SQL tables that mapped controls to roles and view permissions. This allows you to control permissions through the viewmodel and change visibility at any point.

Cinch assists with some of the drudgery of MVVM while allowing you to leverage MEF through [MeffedMVVM](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/an-introduction-to-mefedmvvm-part-1/) or Prism.